# Cannot insert a line into the correct subsection in an xml file using element tree

Tags: python-3.x, elementtree

I am trying to add a line into an xml file using ElementTree in Python 3.4. But I can't seem to get it into the right section.

The line is:

```
<SessionConfiguration File="TestOption1.Invalid.xml" Name="Option3" />
```

Into a config file so it looks like this:

```
<Manager>
  <ConfigurationFiles>
    <SessionConfiguration File="TestOption1.valid.xml" Name="Option1" />
    <SessionConfiguration File="TestOption2.valid.xml" Name="Option2" />
    <SessionConfiguration File="TestOption1.Invalid.xml" Name="Option3" />
  </ConfigurationFiles>
</Manager>
```

Code:

```
    file = "config.xml"
    parent = et.Element("ConfigurationFiles")
    node = et.SubElement(parent, 'SessionConfiguration', Name='Option3', File='TestOption1.Invalid.xml')
    tree = et.parse(file) 
    root = tree.getroot()
    root.insert(2, node)
    tree.write(file)
```

The issue is I cannot seem to insert into [ConfigurationFiles], but its appearing before it.

```
<Manager>
  <SessionConfiguration="TestOption1.Invalid.xml" Name="Option3" />
    <ConfigurationFiles>
        <SessionConfiguration File="TestOption1.valid.xml" Name="Option1" />
        <SessionConfiguration File="TestOption2.valid.xml" Name="Option2" />
    </ConfigurationFiles>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create a new parent element. Instead, get a reference to the existing parent and [append](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.append) the new element to it.

Original config.xml:

```
<Manager>
  <ConfigurationFiles>
    <SessionConfiguration File="TestOption1.valid.xml" Name="Option1" />
    <SessionConfiguration File="TestOption2.valid.xml" Name="Option2" />
  </ConfigurationFiles>
</Manager>
```

Code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

file = "config.xml"
tree = et.parse(file) 

# Find the parent 
parent = tree.find(".//ConfigurationFiles")

# Create the new element
node = et.Element('SessionConfiguration', Name='Option3', File='TestOption1.Invalid.xml')

# Append the new element
parent.append(node)

tree.write("config2.xml")
```

Resulting output in config2.xml:

```
<Manager>
  <ConfigurationFiles>
    <SessionConfiguration File="TestOption1.valid.xml" Name="Option1" />
    <SessionConfiguration File="TestOption2.valid.xml" Name="Option2" />
  <SessionConfiguration File="TestOption1.Invalid.xml" Name="Option3" /></ConfigurationFiles>
</Manager>
```

Comment: Thanks. Perfect answer.